# Create doodling feature like Snapchat

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app in which I want to integrate a feature using which user can take screenshot, doodle something on it and then send it via mail.

How to implement this? I just need a pen for doodling and an eraser to erase last doodle.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library :

[ActiveDoodle](https://github.com/fabrik42/activedoodle/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

You can display two ImageViews on top of each other: the bottom one containing the photo, the top one containing an initially transparent `Bitmap`. In the top ImageView's `onTouchEvent()` method you can transform touch events into strokes of pen applied to the bitmap using a `Canvas`. You might want to read up on [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)s and [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)es.

After the user is done with doodling, you can load the screenshot to a `Bitmap`, rescale the doodle bitmap to match the screenshot's size, and draw in on top, again using a `Canvas`. Reading about [Porter/Duff algebra](http://ssp.impulsetrain.com/porterduff.html) will probably prove useful with applying an `XferMode` to a [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html).

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot.